# Temp table caching with spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is a table registered with `registerTempTable` (`createOrReplaceTempView` with **spark 2.+**)  cached?

Using Zeppelin, I register a `DataFrame` in my scala code, after heavy computation, and then within `%pyspark` I want to access it, and further filter it.

Will it use a memory-cached version of the table? Or will it be rebuilt each time?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Registered tables are not cached in memory.

The <strike>`registerTempTable`</strike> `createOrReplaceTempView` method will just create or replace a view of the given `DataFrame` with a given query plan.

It will convert the query plan to canonicalized SQL string, and store it as view text in metastore, if we need to create a permanent view.

You'll need to cache your DataFrame explicitly. e.g :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table") # df.registerTempTable("my_table") for spark <2.+
spark.cacheTable("my_table")
```

**EDIT:**

Let's illustrate this with an example :

**Using `cacheTable`** :

```
scala> val df = Seq(("1",2),("b",3)).toDF
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: int]

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res0: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> spark.catalog.cacheTable("my_table") // spark.cacheTable("...") before spark 2.0

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res4: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] =
// Map(2 -> In-memory table my_table MapPartitionsRDD[2] at
// cacheTable at <console>:26)
```

Now the same example **using <strike>`cache.registerTempTable`</strike> `cache.createOrReplaceTempView`** :

```
scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> val df = Seq(("1",2),("b",3)).toDF
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: int]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res4: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map()

scala> df.cache.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
// res6: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = 
// Map(2 -> ConvertToUnsafe
// +- LocalTableScan [_1#0,_2#1], [[1,2],[b,3]]
//  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at cache at <console>:28)
```

Comment: So df.cache.registerTempTable is useless actually?

Comment: @toofrellik what do you mean ?

Comment: So how different is `cacheTable` from `cache.createOrReplaceTempView` are they both same in terms of functionality and performance

Comment: @toofrellik `cacheTable` and `cache` have the same behavior but not the same plan as you can see above. The OP wan't to know how he/she can cache a temporary table, because `createOrReplaceTempView` alone doesn't do that.

Answer (score 7):

It is not. You should cache explicitly:

```
sqlContext.cacheTable("someTable")
```