# What role Spark SQL acts? Memory DB?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Recently i come to Spark SQL.
I read the Data Source Api and still confused at what role Spark SQL acts.

When i do SQL on whatever i need, will spark load all the data first and perform sql in memory? That means spark sql is only a memory db that works on data already loaded. Or it scan locally every time?

Really willing to any answers.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> I read the Data Source Api and still confused at what role Spark SQL acts.

Spark SQL is not a database. It is just an interface that allows you to execute SQL-like queries over the data that you store in Spark specific row-based structures called `DataFrame`

To run a SQL query via Spark, the first requirement is that the table on which you are trying to run a query should be present in either the Hive Metastore (i.e the table should be present in Hive) or it should be a temporary view that is part of the current `SQLContext`/`HiveContext`.

So, if you have a dataframe `df` and you want to run SQL queries over it, you can either use:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")     // or registerTempTable
```

and then you can use the `SQLContext`/`HiveContext` or the `SparkSession` to run queries over it.

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_table")
```

[Here's eliasah's answer that explains how `createOrReplaceTempView` works internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249031/7224597)

> When i do SQL on whatever i need, will spark load all the data first and perform sql in memory?

The data will be stored in-memory or on disk depending upon the persistence strategy that you use. If you choose to `cache` the table, the data will get stored in memory and the operations would be considerable faster when compared to the case where data is fetched from the disk. That part is anyway configurable and up to the user. You can basically tell Spark how you want it to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

Spark-sql will only cache the rows that are pulled by the action, this means that it will cache as many partitions as it has to read during the action. this makes your first call much faster than your second call