# how can I broadcast the tempTable instead of "sort merge join" when I use sparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, broadcast

I set the autoBroadcast 200M ,table a is 20KB , table b is 20KB ,table c is 100G.
I found "a left join b on..." is a "broadcast join" and register the result as "TempTable" (TempTable is 30KB),my question is when I do "c left join TempTable on...",I expect that autobroadcast the TempTable to make a broadcast join but it made a sort merge join.I also tried cache the TempTable and broadcast DataFrame of the TempTable,but it doesn't work...
How can I broadcast the TempTable to make a broadcast join with sparkSQL?
I'm using spark-1.6.1
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] so you can receive an adequate solution.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248621/temp-table-caching-with-spark-sql

Comment: @abhijitnag I want to broadcast the temptable,not to register or cache it...

Answer (score 2):

Though it's very difficult to understand without any code snippet what you have tried so far. I am sharing some sample code tried at Spark 2.3 where broadcast function applied on Temp View(as Temp table is deprecated in Spark2). In following scala code, I have forcefully use broadcast hash join.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val adf = spark.range(99999999)
val bdf = spark.range(99999999)
adf.createOrReplaceTempView("a")
bdf.createOrReplaceTempView("b")
val bdJoinDF = spark.sql("select /*+ BROADCASTJOIN(b) */a.id, b.id from a join b on a.id = b.id")
val normalJoinDF = spark.sql("select a.id, b.id from a join b on a.id = b.id")
println(normalJoinDF.queryExecution) //== Physical Plan == *(5) SortMergeJoin [id#39512L], [id#39514L], Inner
println(bdJoinDF.queryExecution) //== Physical Plan == *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#39611L], [id#39613L], Inner, BuildRight, false
```

Comment: @Figo Let me know, whether the above approach help you or not

Comment: I can only use spark1.6