# How to use cache table for further queries in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

I am reading around 500GB of data from HDFS, performing aggregations and creating an `agg_Master_table` table which is the output of `sqlContext.sql("....")` query

I need to use this `agg_Master_table` table for further queries hence i created temp table using:

```
agg_master_table.createOrReplaceTempView("AggMasterTable")
```

But when I run the further queries on top of `UserAggMasterTable` it is reading data from HDFS again, I don't want this to happen hence I am using:

```
sqlContext.sql("CACHE TABLE AggMasterTableCache").collect()
```

so that data can be stored in memory and further queries can be resulted out quickly, but now I am not able to do 
`AggMasterTableCache.show()` or use it in `sqlContext.sql("Select * from AggMasterTableCache")`

How do we make use of cache table here.

Comment: `collect` will move all data to the driver, that is probably not what you want to do. You are looking for `cacheTable`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248621/temp-table-caching-with-spark-sql

Comment: So how different is `cacheTable` from `cache.createOrReplaceTempView` are the both same in terms of functionality and performance

Comment: got an amazing [post](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/271/should-i-always-cache-my-rdds.html) which answers this question

Answer (score 1):

Adding `agg_master_table.persist()` before first calculation should do the trick.
On first calculation, data will be read from HDFS and stored, so the further reads of agg_master_table data frame will use the stored data

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a temporary view in spark, you can cache it using the following code. When you check spark UI, you can see that after first read, it's basically not reading from HDFS again.

```
spark.catalog.cacheTable("AggMasterTableCache")
```

Note: You have basically cached the temporary view not the dataframe so any tranformation/action on top of the dataframe, it would result in reading from the source again i believe.